# Write JQL to find an issue that has subissues

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jql, jira-rest-java-api

JQL to check issues of type Fix that have non empty issue links. I need issues under the resolves as shown below in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [Scriptrunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=cloud) installed on your Jira instance, you can use

```
issuetype = fix and issueFunction in hasLinks()
```

The hasLinks issue function allows you to specify the link type if you want to filter for specific links.

Answer (score -1):

use the following JQL:

```
issuelinktype = "resolves"
```